# Populating morris chart in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem when trying to populate morris chart dynamically.

This is the JSON string:

```
[{"Name":"Paul Walker","ExamQuantity":35},{"Name":"Vin Diesel","ExamQuantity":1}]
```

Then in javascript I do this:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.TeacherExams));   

       new Morris.Bar({
       element: 'chartTeacherExams',
       data: model,
       xkey: 'Name',
       ykeys: ['ExamQuantity'],
        labels: ['Quantidade']
   });
```

But when the chart loads, I get this image:

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai No.

Comment: Try replace `data: model` with `data:[{"Name":"Paul Walker","ExamQuantity":35},{"Name":"Vin Diesel","ExamQuantity":1}]`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai It works like a charm... and when I show an alert with 'model' variable, it shows the same information. I think Json.Serialize is not creating the object properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try change `data:model` using your json array.

In your case, use: `data:[{"Name":"Paul Walker","ExamQuantity":35},{"Name":"Vin Diesel","ExamQuantity":1}]`.Array is already in JSON format.

The mistake is in this line: `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.TeacherExams));`

`Json.Serialize` turns JSON object to JSON string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your tip. I removed `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.TeacherExams));` and added this: `var info = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.TeacherExams)');`. And then it worked!!!